# Pass value between forms and DevExpress gridviews

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have two forms, one parent with the `gridview1` and the other child form `gridview2`, when the parent form is clicked on the cell it displays the child form with the information help in the `gridview2`.

How can I get the selected value in the `gridview2` child form and display it in the `gridview1` cell?

it occurs to me to call from the child an event in the parent that passes the value of the `gridview2` but does not take the grid and the cell with the value is not updated.

Form child :

```
value= gridview2.GetRowCellValue(info.RowHandle, "columnselected")

    Dim formParent As New FormParent()


                    formParent.confirmValueGrid(value)
```

Form parent gridview1

```
 Public Sub confirmValueGrid(value As String)
        Try

            If value.ToString <> "" And clm.Substring(0, 6).Equals("columntoDisplay") Then

                ''row = gridview1.GetSelectedRows(irow) ' e.FocusedRowHandle = 2 still 
                gridview1.SetRowCellValue(row, clm, value)
                gridview1.UpdateCurrentRow()
                'gridview1_LostFocus(Me, Nothing)


            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Catch
            'ignore
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Which language is it? If it is Visual Basic, add the _vba_ tag

Comment: It doesn't seem like you want to be creating a new instance of FormParent. You should instead be passing the existing instance to FormChild, or retrieving the instance via FormChild.Owner (assuming you set this before opening FormChild).